# How to fire intent android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, imageview

i am building a game, the goal of the game is to prevent the images from falling, what i want is that when the image reaches the bottom of the screen, it will call an intent to start new activity .Please help me. I manage to make the images fall, what i want to know is how to trigger intent when the image reaches the bottom of the screen.

```
package com.example.crashthetrash;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Game extends Activity {

int posy;
int posy2;
int posy3;
int posy4;
int posy5;
int posy6;
int dur;
int dur2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

      dur = 5000;
      dur2 = dur - 10;

      final ImageView chips = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chips);

      final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation.setDuration(dur);
      animation.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation.setFillAfter(true);
      chips.startAnimation(animation);


      chips.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              posy = chips.getTop();
              posy2 = 0 - posy;
              dur2 = dur2 - 100;

              TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy2, 500.0f);
              animation.setDuration(dur2);
              animation.setRepeatCount(0);
              animation.setRepeatMode(0);
              animation.setFillAfter(true);
              chips.startAnimation(animation);

            return true;
        }
    });


      final ImageView fish = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fish);

      final TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation2.setDuration(dur);
      animation2.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation2.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation2.setFillAfter(true);
      fish.startAnimation(animation2);

      fish.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  posy3 = fish.getTop();
                  posy4 = 0 - posy;
                  dur2 = dur2 - 100;

                  TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy4, 500.0f);
                  animation2.setDuration(dur2);
                  animation2.setRepeatCount(0);
                  animation2.setRepeatMode(0);
                  animation2.setFillAfter(true);
                  fish.startAnimation(animation2);
                return true;
            }
        });

      final ImageView paper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.paper);

      final TranslateAnimation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation3.setDuration(dur);
      animation3.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation3.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation3.setFillAfter(true);
      paper.startAnimation(animation3);


      paper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  posy5 = paper.getTop();
                  posy6 = 0 - posy;
                  dur2 = dur2 - 100;

                  TranslateAnimation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy6, 500.0f);
                  animation3.setDuration(dur2);
                  animation3.setRepeatCount(0);
                  animation3.setRepeatMode(0);
                  animation3.setFillAfter(true);
                  paper.startAnimation(animation3);
                return true;
            }
        });

      if(animation.hasEnded() || animation2.hasEnded() || animation3.hasEnded())
      {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }

}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}





}
```

Comment: and which field are you poiting at?

Comment: Your intent -code looks proper just check whether your pointer goes inside of your IF loop or not

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. im new to eclipse.can you please show me what you mean through my codes. thank you so much.

Comment: everything is working, only the {if}  statement.

Comment: also im thinking if i can use switch for this. please help. :D